# How do I enable GZIP compression for WCF services on AppHarbor?

Tags: appharbor

I'd like to get GZIP compression working for my webservices that I'm serving on AppHarbor, however it looks like this tweak needs to be done using the IIS admin console (to enable "Dynamic Compression on IIS 7").

Since we don't have access to an IIS control panel on AppHarbor (not generally a bad thing!) is there a way to enable this setting?

http://www.traviswhidden.com/PublicBlog/tabid/358/EntryId/420/asp-net-and-wcf-compression-via-IIS.aspx

Comment: It's been a few years since this question but appHarbor is using nginx, my assets are not been compressed what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Gzip compression is enabled out-of-the-box on AppHarbor (except for clients that don't support it). You can verify using this tool: http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/

Comment: Thanks friism. It looks like my webservices are being compressed when I query them directly. That tool is very useful. I guess I'll have to turn my attention to the proxy server I'm using!

Comment: Great, please accept the answer if you feel it answered your question.